# How to get phpMyAdmin to run on schedule a URL

Tags: phpmyadmin

I'm using Codeigniter to create my website. When I call a URL that function does a load of magic stuff.

How can I get phpMyAdmin to run that URL every morning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Cron Job functions in your server, not PhPMyAdmin. Later is only for better database access